# Why won't this html segment recognice my javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I am rendering a graph with a couple of input fields using a function in WordPress. The js file is definitely available to this section of the html because the graph is rendering. It is included through the enqueue_script function in wp. However, when I try to set the onclick function (updateChart()), I get an error saying my function isn't defined. Been at it for a while... Any ideas?

I have tried importing the script directl into the head above the tags I am trying to call it in.

```
        ob_start();?>

    <head>
            <!–– All styling should take place below ––>
                <!–– First div id must match the first argument of Chart Object in js file ––>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='chartContainer' style='height: 300px; width: 100%;'></div>
        <input type='number' id='voltage' placeholder='Voltage' step='0.01' />
        <input type='number' id='amperage' placeholder='Amperage' step='0.01' />
        <button id ='simulate' onclick= 'updateChart()' >Simulate</button>
    </body>

<?php
        $content = ob_get_clean();
        echo($content);
    }
```

The js code should get the input fields and update the chart using them.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in the line of code from which you're calling the function is correct.

```
<button id ='simulate' onclick= 'updateChart()' >Simulate</button>
```

When issues like these arise for me I usually add in some `console.log()` 's into the code to see what is actually executing.

Firstly, you say that the JS file is being called properly but just to make sure add in a `console.log` into the JS file and see if it shows in the console window.

Secondly, create a very simple function like..

```
function myFunction() {
  console.log("Hello");
}
```

then call this function in your view like..

```
<button id ='simulate' onclick= 'myFunction()' >Simulate</button>
```

If 'Hello' appears in the console window then the issue is with the `updateChart()` function and not the implementation.